# How to reinstall ubuntu from flash drive

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I am using ubuntu 13.04 and wish to reinstall ubuntu using a usb flash drive.  Currently my computer is set up to dual boot with windows 7 and ubuntu, where grub comes up when i boot the computer i can choose either.  Is there an easy way to remove windows completely and reinstall only ubuntu?

I have all files backed up so i would prefer to just reinstall the os from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Boot into your USB stick from your bios. This varies from manufacturer to manufacturer, but mine is F12. When installing Ubuntu from the flash drive, you will have the option to erase the entire disk and install Ubuntu.

Comment: He says, "Is there a way to remove Windows completely and install Ubuntu?"

Comment: opps, sorry I misread that part....I thought he only wanted to renistall Ubuntu.....